# Native query works sqlDeveloper but fails using hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have a query that i want to run it using hibernate native sqlQuery

when i run query using sql developer it works fine but when hibernate run it ,it throws this exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3319) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.findColumn(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1926) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getLong(OracleResultSet.java:1575) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:789) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
```

this is the query from hibernate logs :

```
Hibernate: select o.GUICHET,count(*) from OPERATIONS o, Guichet g, Centre c where DATE_OPERATIONS between trunc(sysdate,'mm') and add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),1) and c.centre_id=? and c.centre_id=g.centre_id and g.GUICHET_ID=o.GUICHET group by o.GUICHET
```

here's my table class definition :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "operations")
public class Operations implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private Long operationsId;
    private Date dateOperations;
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "guichet", referencedColumnName = "guichetId")
    private Guichet guichet;
```

Edit : here's the code where im defining this method and using it

```
@Repository
public interface OperationsRepository extends CrudRepository<Operations, Long> {

    @Query(value="select o.guichet,count(*) from OPERATIONS o, Guichet g, Centre c where DATE_OPERATIONS between trunc(sysdate,'mm') and add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),1) " + 
            "and c.centre_id=?1 and c.centre_id=g.centre_id and g.GUICHET_ID=o.GUICHET " + 
            "group by o.guichet",nativeQuery=true)
    Iterable<Operations> operationsStat( Long centreId);
```

Using this method :

```
@Override
    public Iterable<Operations> operationsStat(Long centreId) {
        return operationsRepository.operationsStat(centreId);
    }


@GetMapping(value="/statistique")
    @ResponseBody()
    Iterable<Operations> doStatistique()
    {
        return operationsServiceImpl.operationsStat(new Long(selectedCentre)); 
    }
```

Comment: `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name` means that your query is working ok, but your resulset is not getting the column name because that column name doesn't exist on the query.  Maybe the error is coming from the part of the code where you are trying to read the values that comes from the custom query.  Could you provide that part where you read the values that comes from the query?

Comment: before that, the query works and returns results if i provide the rest of the table columns names in the select and group by , but i don't get the results i wanted.

Comment: im simply returning this iterable method to ajax call so i can loop threw it. not accessing any value in it in java

Comment: ok, also looking at the stacktrace there is also `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getLong` that means that your are trying to read a long value, but I couldn't in the code where is occurring that read operation.

Comment: look at the edit i added the code

Answer (score 2):

Code after changing the return type :

```
@Repository
public interface OperationsRepository extends CrudRepository<Operations, Long> {

    @Query(value="select o.guichet,count(*) from OPERATIONS o, Guichet g, Centre c where DATE_OPERATIONS between trunc(sysdate,'mm') and add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),1) " + 
            "and c.centre_id=?1 and c.centre_id=g.centre_id and g.GUICHET_ID=o.GUICHET " + 
            "group by o.guichet",nativeQuery=true)
    Iterable<Object> operationsStat( Long centreId);
```

then this :

```
@Override
    public Iterable<Object> operationsStat(Long centreId) {
        return operationsRepository.operationsStat(centreId);
    }


@GetMapping(value="/statistique")
    @ResponseBody()
    Iterable<Object> doStatistique()
    {
        return operationsServiceImpl.operationsStat(new Long(selectedCentre)); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a field in the Operations class

```
private Date dateOperations;
```

But the query does not return any value for the field. The same for

```
private Guichet guichet;
```

No column guichetId in  the query and your `count(*)` has no mapped field in the class.

Comment: i don't want to return a value for both of those fields in intrested in count of all rows for each guichet (guichet_id)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `@Query(value="select o.guichet,count(*) from OPERATIONS o ..` is returning a List of `Guichet` objects but you are expecting a `List<Operations>`.

One options is to create an external pojo for your Operations statics (using for example a package name: com.myorg.model)

```
package com.myorg.model;
 public class OperationsStas {
  private Guichet guichet;
  private Long   count;

  public OperationsStas(Guichet guichet, Long count) {
    this.guichet = guichet;
    this.count  = count;
  }
```

}

The repo could be like this:

```
@Repository
public interface OperationsRepository extends CrudRepository<Operations, Long> {

    @Query(value="select new com.myorg.model.com.myorg.model.OperationsStats(o.guichet,count(*)) from OPERATIONS o, Guichet g, Centre c where DATE_OPERATIONS between trunc(sysdate,'mm') and add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),1) " + 
            "and c.centre_id=?1 and c.centre_id=g.centre_id and g.GUICHET_ID=o.GUICHET " + 
            "group by o.guichet",nativeQuery=true)
    List<OperationsStas> operationsStat( Long centreId);
```

And also the control have to change

```
@Override
    public List<OperationsStas> operationsStat(Long centreId) {
        return operationsRepository.operationsStat(centreId);
    }


@GetMapping(value="/statistique")
    @ResponseBody()
    List<OperationsStas> doStatistique()
    {
        return operationsServiceImpl.operationsStat(new Long(selectedCentre)); 
    }
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: thanks for making me notice the return type i'm so blind, i only had to change it to object and let the compiler do it's job, now it works

Comment: yes with object return type is also an alternative.  if you want you can post your alternative is can help other people with similar problem.